# How to run a java testNg project's jar in server?

Tags: java, testng

I created a java-testNg project in eclipse.I had another java spring project in which i want to upload that testNg project to sever folder and run it from server.
      On upload time i created the jar of testNg project and i am uploading that jar.Can anybody help how to run that testNg project on server...any ideas....plz help

Comment: is batch file (.bat) will help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [run TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng) from the command line.

You can execute command line statements from Java using a [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is my pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
    <!-- the main function-->
        <start-class>org.kuohai.TestNGMain</start-class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.uncommons</groupId>
            <artifactId>reportng</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>packageName</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>none</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.17</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>src/main/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>

                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            <name>usedefaultlisteners</name>
                            <value>false</value>
                        </property>
                        <property>
                            <name>listener</name>
                            <value>org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter,
                                org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter
                            </value>
                        </property>
                    </properties>      
                    <forkMode>always</forkMode>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.springframework.boot.maven.PropertiesMergingResourceTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/spring.factories</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

This is the main function

```java
package org.kuohai;

public class TestNGMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        org.testng.TestNG.main(args);
    }
}
```

then you can use mvn clean package -DskipTests

Package and run

java -jar packageName.jar -testjar packageName.jar

If you have other questions, you can run java -jar packageName.jar You can see the message